# PCB mount AC input and output

Tags: power-supply, ac

I’m looking for pcb mount AC power connectors. I’m looking for just the metal connectors to solder to the pcb. I can’t find these anywhere. I will be designing the case around it so i do t need to have the insulation on the part it’s self.
Much like these

The Male[image: Make PCB mount plugs]

The Female  [image: The female connector]

Comment: Hey Bradley. Welcome to the EE Stackexchange. Before you start asking questions, I highly advise you to read [this page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before you start asking things on here. Also, this is a vague question because you're asking for `the minimum`.

Comment: Surprisingly hard to find.. I gave up looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nema pcb mount contacts

found some here ...
https://www.heyco.com/Power_Components/product.cfm?product=PCB-Contacts&section=Power_Components

see bottom of page for mechanical drawings

Comment: Also try Keystone and Zierick (sp?).