# What is the name for PCB mount AC power connectors

Tags: ac, components

What is the search keyword for PCB mount AC power connectors? I'm looking for just the metal connectors (plug and receptacle) for solder to the PCB.

[image: contacts]

I'm asking for the brass connectors shown above.

"nema pcb mount contacts" is close (found from question [PCB mount AC input and output](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/344671/pcb-mount-ac-input-and-output)) but it return results from only one manufacturer that doesn't offer European connectors; which indicates probably there is more appopriate keyword that I can't find (yet)...

Comment: like these?
 https://www.heyco.com/Power_Components/product.cfm?product=PCB-Contacts&section=Power_Components

Comment: Just "PCB mount contacts"? Note that there likely isn't anything specific in their name for voltage or AC. You can design the same connector for any voltages

Answer (score 2):

The IEC has a global designation for AC power connections.  The connector shown is a ["Type B"](http://www.iec.ch/worldplugs/typeB.htm) connector.   Another name in the US is NEMA 5-15R, where the R means receptacle.  Unfortunately, googling that with PCB Mount or Surface Mount Contacts doesn't bring up much.  The only place I found was Heyco, and while they have a [picture](https://www.heyco.com/Power_Components/img/8-53_114b.jpg) of what you are looking for on their website, they don't seem to have a corresponding part number.  Perhaps you could give them a call.

Comment: FWIW, the closest Heyco part number I could find is 7261 "Wiping contact 90 degrees" (https://www.heyco.com/Power_Components/product.cfm?product=PCB-Contacts&section=Power_Components).